# Laravel - How to get select value and pass it to RegisterController create()

Tags: php, laravel, select, roles

I have the following problem, how can I get the value of a select on my `register.blade.php`?

When a user register he should be able to select a `role`, each `role` has an `id` and once he clicks on the `submit` button the `role id` should be assigned to his `rol_id` on `users` table.

But I don't know how to get the value of the selected `id` once I use the `create` method on `RegisterController`.

Part of the `register.blade.php` that has the select:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rol_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Rol:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-select" name="rol_id" id="rol_id">
            <option value="2">User</option>
            <option value="3">Editor</option>
            <option value="1">Admin</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should I put on the `rol_id`? This is the `create` method where I should assign the `id` of the role selected:

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'rol_id' =>
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

If you need more methods/classes I'll provide it.

UPDATE: Also Im facing another problem, once a User is created the rol_id gets assigned, but I have another table called role_user where there is the user id and the rol id, there is no much sense on having that pivot table if users can only have one role right?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `'rol_id' => $data['rol_id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user [@dazed-and-confused](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2704089/dazed-and-confused) shared with you in the question's comments, you must use `'rol_id' => $data['rol_id']`. That is your fix/solution.

Now, I am going to expand a little bit more on why:

> Any `form` you send to any URL (form's `action`), it is going to send any `input`, `textarea` and `select`. But these elements **MUST** have a `name` attribute, in your case it would be `name="rol_id"` (`<select class="form-select" name="rol_id" id="rol_id">`).

So, to read any of these elements in your controller, you have to use `$request->input('NAME_OF_ELEMENT')`, for example: `$request->input('email')`.

You can also send other data types directly like `string`s, `boolean`s, `number`s (integers, float, etc), but you have mostly to do an AJAX call (using [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), for example).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So inside that $data we find all the information sent from a form? I'll do a dd($data) to see all that contains. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, please mark this answer as accepted and +1